# Two questions on complex geometry

Tags: complex-geometry, complex-manifolds, ag.algebraic-geometry

I have two questions on complex geometry.

First one is that why the existence of almost complex structure on tangent bundle on real 2n-dimensional manifold is a topological question?

Wikipedia describes it as a topological question. I think that mean there is some homology or cohomology group associated to topological property whose vanishing or nonvanishing pertains to the existence.

Would you explain why it should be a topological question intuitively and may I suggest exact topological invariant which captures the existence property?

Second, in Huybrechts's book 'Complex Geometry',
when it comes to Euler exact sequence on $P^n$, he mentioned that there is natural inclusion map such that $O(-1)\rightarrow\oplus_{j=0}^{n}O$.
I can hardly come up with any idea on what this inclusion map is.

If possible, would you let me know the exact expression for this map?
(here, $O(-1)$ is the tautological line bundle sheaf on $P^n$ and $O$ is the holomorphic sheaf of the trivial line bundle)

Hoping to get some shedding light in your reply.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(1)  Why is the existence of an almost-complex structure a topological question?  Suppose $M$ is a $2n$-manifold.  The tangent bundle is classified by some map $M\to BGL_{2n}(\mathbb{R})$; $M$ admits an almost-complex structure if and only if this map admits a lift to $BGL_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ (that is, an almost-complex structure is the same as endowing the tangent bundle with the structure of a complex vector bundle).  The existence of such a lift depends only on the homotopy type of the map $M\to BGL_{2n}(\mathbb{R})$, and is thus a topological question.  As such, it can be analyzed via standard methods in obstruction theory, which I will leave for you to google.

(2)  Suppose we have a projective space $\mathbb{P}V$, where $V$ is some vector space of dimension $n+1$. Then a map $X\to\mathbb{P}V$ is the same as a line bundle $\mathcal{L}$ on $X$ and a surjective map $V\otimes \mathcal{O}_X\to \mathcal{L}$. The identity map on $\mathbb{P}V$ classifies such data---namely, a map $V\otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{P}V}\to \mathcal{O}(1)$.  Explicitly, this map is given by identifying the global sections of $\mathcal{O}(1)$ with $V$, via the standard computation of the cohomology of line bundles on projective space.

Now your map is dual of this map.  (Picking a basis $(x_i)$ of $V=\Gamma(\mathbb{P}V, \mathcal{O}(1))$, this map is given by multiplication by $(x_i)$.)

By the way, the Euler exact sequence admits a very geometric interpretation.  Namely, there is a sequence of maps $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}\to \mathbb{P}^n\to \operatorname{pt}$, where the first map is the usual quotient by $\mathbb{C}^*$.  This induces a short exact sequence of cotangent bundles $$0\to \pi^*\Omega^1_{\mathbb{P}^n}\to \Omega^1_{\mathbb{A}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}}\to \Omega^1_{(\mathbb{A}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\})/\mathbb{P}^n}\to 0.$$

Each of these sheaves admits an (equivariant) action of $\mathbb{C}^*$, and so descend to sheaves on $\mathbb{P}^n$, giving exactly the Euler exact sequence.

Comment: Dear Daniel, Thanks for great reply penetrating the fundamentals. Due to my ignorance, I can't fully grasp your answer, but it stimulate me to study more. After studying related some concepts appearing your answer and a meditatin,and then I will look again your reply. Thanks in advance for hindsight I will get before long.

Regards,

Comment: I'm happy I could help, Jude--is there any specific point on which you'd like clarification?

Comment: Dear Daniel, Thanks for your kindness. On your first reply, you mentioned there is some map classifying tangent bundles but I don't know what the map is such. If it is not so rude and the answer might be simple, would you explain some basic idea underlies the construction of the map? 

Comment: @Jude:  Real vector bundles of rank $n$ over a finite CW complex $X$ are naturally in bijection with homotopy classes of maps from $X\to BGL_n(\mathbb{R})$, e.g. the Grassmannian of $n$-planes in $\mathbb{R}^\infty$.  This is a well-known fact from algebraic topology; see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifying_space

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks again. Classifying spaces is the one I didn't know yet. I am sorry for asking some basic question and really grateful for your benovelence.(espescially making a kind link to wiki)

Answer (score 4):

Answer to the second question. Represent $\mathbb P^n$ as the space of lines (1-dimensional linear subspaces) in the $(n+1)$-dimensional vector space $E$. Then $O_{\mathbf P^n}(-1)$ is the linear bundle on $\mathbb P^n$ s.t. its fiber over the point of $\mathbb P^n$ corresponding to the line $\ell\subset E$ is the line $\ell$ itself. This bundle is naturally embedded in the trivial bundle with the fiber $E$, which becomes isomorphic to $O^{n+1}$ once you have chosen a basis in $E$.

Comment: Dear Serge, Thanks for your clear remark. You enlightened the point I am missing.

Answer (score 3):

If $(x_0:x_1:\dots:x_n)$ are the homogeneous coordinates on $P^n$ then the map $O(-1) \to O^{n+1}$ is given by $s \mapsto (sx_0,sx_1,\dots,sx_n)$.

Comment: Thanks Sasha. At first glimpse, it seems a little weird because sxi is not an element in O. However, in Serge's reply, I can see the point you are meaning. Thanks for suggesting explicit map